# How was the effect of Alderaan blowing up accomplished?

Tags: effects, star-wars, a-new-hope

A special effect sequence in the original Star Wars (1977) shows the planet Alderaan being blown up by the Death Star (frame shown below). Considering that this was the pre-digital era, I thought the explosion was really well done. How did they do it?

[image: Alderaan Blown Up (1977)]

Obviously some pyrotechnics were used, but what were they to make such a cool looking explosion?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I eventually found out that it was done using an ordinary black powder exposion in slightly slow motion.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the original, unaltered clip here:

If you're interested in all the special effects, there's a great documentary called [Empire Of Dreams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfqeFs7PODI).

It was basically comprised of a scale model which was blown up, against a blue screen so the space background could be added later.

Comment: Ok, but what were the pyrotechnics specifically?

Comment: @TylerDurden - Bottle rockets.  They put a whole bunch in a huge papermache piñata, then waited until the planet blew.